# jndi clustering

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, jndi, cluster-computing

I have a few questions about JNDi and clustring:

1. When an EJB is deployed is it automatically "registered" in the JNDI?
2. I read that for acessing a clustered EJB of WebSphere I need to lookup something like: "cell/cluster//ejb/... - is the "cell" concept a Websphere concept or a J2EE concept?
3. I have a weird demand - I want to cluster, but not neccesarily using WebSphere - That is, I have a WebSphere cluster: C consisitng of servers A and B, and also I have another websphere server D with different application deployed than A and B, but with the same SessionBean interface, same API. I want to be able to create a load-balanced/clustered call to the EJB and let it once execute on A, once on B and once on D.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. But it depends on deployment descriptor/annotations of EJB.
2. It's a term from WebSphere (http://itdevworld.wordpress.com/2009/05/03/websphere-concepts-cell-node-cluster-server/).
3. As far as I know if you deploy your EJB to the cluster it is automatically load-balanced.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, an EJB is always made available for lookup via JNDI after it's deployed. This is mandated by the EJB spec. The name under which it is inserted is standardized. See [EJB-Naming and directory services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean#Naming_and_directory_services) on wikipedia.
2. "cell" is Websphere specific. Although the Java EE spec in general and specifically the EJB spec do assume clustering exists and put several limitations in place to make clustering easier, there are surprisingly little APIs and naming standards defined that deal explicitly with clustering (JCA 1.6 is one of the few that comes to mind).
3. This indeed sounds weird. If I understand correctly, only 3 calls in total are allowed (1 to A, 1 to B and 1 to D) and then all service should stop? Maybe you should not want something like this ;)

Comment: I think he wants WLM round robin routing.

Comment: Could be indeed ;) Perhaps it's better suited as the topic for a separate question about load balancing strategies.

Answer (score 0):

1. The registration is actually done when the EJB application is started up. It uses the DD information to register with the WAS JNDI Server
2. What you are referring to is referred to as the fully qualified JNDI Name. You should try and not use that and simply work with local JNDI names. Why? The fully qualified name has the topology specific information and you would not be using these in your application as the topologies would be different between development, test and prod environments. The whole idea of local name spaces was to hide the way the various vendors store and have the application not have any dependency on the vendor implementation(s)
3. Clustering in WAS works iwth the premise that the same application is deployed to all the servers that are part of hte cluster. In fact, if a server is part of a cluster, you cannot deploy an application to that server. It can only be deployed to the cluster level and the WAS infrastructure deploys the same application to all the cluster members.

Round-robin is a WLM policy which can be configured on the server. The other option  is having weightage for each cluster member.

HTH

Manglu